# Can you help me crack this code my friend gave me?

Tags: encoded-message

My friend gave me this code and I just cannot crack it.

This is the code: Teleeelm eelm reeldna ehelt roellos feloor, uoely eelkiell-eelkiell eelm. teeelt eelm noel.

My friend is a  sort of bad speller, so this may be hard.

Answer (score 5):

When I first saw the string, the first thing the first few words reminded me of was "meet me at the".

It appears that the string `el`, wherever it appears should be removed.

This gives us:

> Teem em redna eht rolos foor, uoy ekil-ekil em. teet em no.

And if we reverse the letters in each word, we get:

> Meet me ander the solor roof, you like-like me. Teet me on.

It appears that some of the words have either been deliberately or inadvertently mangled, because it looks like it *should* be this:

> Meet me under the solar roof, (you like-like me). Meet me on [message cut off].

I can't figure out what the part in parentheses means, but at least they're English words.

Comment: "To  like-like someone" means to like them as more than a friend. That's what it made me think of

Comment: I usually stylize that as "I *like* like you", with the first one in italics, though (to indicate emphasis).

Comment: Yeah, that seems more natural. But I can also see someone doing it some other way

Answer (score 1):

I reversed it and removed some letters:

```
on me teet. me like-like you, roof solor the ander me meet
```

Though, I may have removed letters i shouldn't have, or not enough. Anyway, this is the best I can do. Someone could take it further..

Comment: Reversing the letters in each word but not the order of the words might be better